# How to set the default tag for jEdit windows in Awesome WM?

Tags: awesome, window-management

[The following rule](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/a7816a7581f5c58d8bfabbb19b3f1987de540aea/.config/awesome/rc.lua#L428-L429) works as expected:

```
{ rule = { class = "Firefox" },
  properties = { tag = tags[2][2] } },
```

That is, Firefox instances are started on the second tag of the second screen. However, I have not been able to do the same for jEdit with this rule on the next line:

```
{ rule = { class = "jedit" },
  properties = { tag = tags[2][3] } },
```

jEdit instances always pop up on the first tag of the first screen. The [window class](https://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/FAQ#How_to_find_window.27s_class_and_other_identifiers.3F) looks correct:

```
$ xprop | grep "^WM_CLASS\|^WM_NAME" 
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "sun-awt-X11-XFramePeer", "jedit"
WM_NAME(STRING) = "jEdit - Untitled-1"
```

Except for the capitalization it's very similar to the result for Firefox:

```
$ xprop | grep "^WM_CLASS\|^WM_NAME" 
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "Navigator", "Firefox"
WM_NAME(STRING) = "How to place jEdit window in Awesome WM? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange - Mozilla Firefox"
```

[Mocking the WM name](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85640/how-to-place-jedit-window-in-awesome-wm#comment127599_85640) doesn't work either - after running the following the window still appears in the wrong place:

```
sudo pacman --sync wmname
wmname LG3D
jedit &
```

Java version:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.3) (ArchLinux build 7.u45_2.4.3-1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

What's happening here?

Comment: Can you include `xprop` output for Firefox?

Comment: Can you also try mocking the window manager name using this: `wmname LG3D` ... Some Java application doesn't like awesome for some reason. http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Problems_with_Java

Comment: So I installed awesome via apt-get on Ubuntu 12.04. My xprop output is slightly different. I copied the class into the config and started jedit. It started on the second tag like it was supposed to, no problems. All I did was copy the Firefox section from the default config, uncomment it, and put the right class in. You could try specifying the instance and the class. Maybe that will help you?

Comment: @SeanPerry If it works for you, could you please post the actual configuration as an answer?

Comment: I did not because it was basically the same as your config except for the different WM_CLASS. That was why I suggested you try both the instance and the class rather than just the class.

Answer (score 1):

Works on Ubuntu with 100% packaged components:

```
-- Set jedit to always map on tags number 2 of screen 1.
{ rule = { class = "org-gjt-sp-jedit-jEdit" },
  properties = { tag = tags[1][2] } },
```

This also works for me:

```
-- with instance
{ rule = { class = "org-gjt-sp-jedit-jEdit", instance = "sun-awt-X11-XFramePeer",  },
  properties = { tag = tags[1][2] } },
```

This is awesome 3.4.11 and jedit 4.4.2+dfsg-1 with java:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.6) (6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

xprop output:

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "sun-awt-X11-XFramePeer", "org-gjt-sp-jedit-jEdit"
WM_NAME(STRING) = "jEdit - Untitled-1"
```

Comment: Neither of these worked with my setup.

Comment: Disappointing. I wonder if the Java distribution has something to do with it. You are probably using the Oracle/Sun distribution and not the open LDK one, right? Just you could try running jEdit with a different JDK just to see if it works. That ought to help track down the bug to the right place.

Comment: Nope, using OpenJDK.